# How to get files from a VM to host machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, scp

My host machine is Ubuntu. I am running a debian VM on virtualbox. I want to get files from the VM to the host machine. I tried to use scp by doing the command from the VM:

scp filename host_username@my_ip:/path/to/folder

However I get a connection timed out error lost connection. The ip address I use is the ip4 address from when I google my ip.
Is there an easier or better way to do this?

Comment: Did you install the equivalent of Tools on Virtual Box? (Virtual Box Guest extensions). Are you using Bridged Networking? (Makes file sharing easier).

Comment: I tried to make a shared folder using guest extensions, but every tutorial I found online involved windows or using a gui my VM is only a terminal. I don't know what bridged networking is.

Comment: Look in your VM settings. Virtual Box should provide for at least NAT and Bridged Network settings in the Network settings area.

Answer (score 0):

> However I get a connection timed out error lost connection. The ip address I use is the ip4 address from when I google my ip. Is there an easier or better way to do this?

Wait... are you trying to connect to your WAN IP address ? Quite unlikely to work.
Instead you should use the **local** IP address of the VM. Probably in the 10.* or 192.168.* range.

Then, the next and most obvious step is to make sure that **SSH** is running on the VM since you want to use SCP and it needs SSH.

One thing you can do is ping the VM from your host, if that doesn't work it's most likely a firewall or routing issue. Then we'll need more information on your network configuration to advise further.

That will depend on whether the VM is configured to use NAT or bridged networking.

But maybe [shared folders](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders) is a better option. NB: you may need to add yourself to the `vboxusers` group.

Comment: How can I tell if I am using NAT or bridged networking. I retried the command with the 10.* ip (thank you) and this time it said connection refused. There are 2 different 10.* ips for the VM and host. I did ping 10.*** and got back
PING 10.**** (10.****) 56(84) bytes of data. I think ssh is running on my VM I did ps -aux | grep ssh

Comment: You first need to determine the IP address of the VM with certainty. Did the ping succeed or not ? Are you running Virtualbox on a headless server or is there another reason why you have no GUI ? Can you describe the steps you followed to install Virtualbox ? Even if SSH is running on your VM, its firewall (`iptables` or other) could still block remote connections. If you type `route -n` in your host what do you get ? or `tracert -n <VM ip>`. This is to verify your routing. You can update the question with the results.

Comment: "How can I tell if I am using NAT or bridged networking. " Look in the Network Settings area in Virtual Box for the Guest machine.